# Traffic Light Code

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Below is my code... it works perfectly fine but...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
    <img id="trafficlights" src="Redlight.jpeg" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
    <button type="button" onclick="changetrafficlights()">Change Traffic Lights</button>
<script>
    var position = 0;
    var list = ["Redlight.jpeg","RedAmberlight.jpeg","Greenlight.jpeg", "Amberlight.jpeg"];  

    function changetrafficlights() 
        {position = position + 1;    
        if(position == list.length){
            position = 0;
        }
        var image = document.getElementById('trafficlights');
        image.src=list[position];}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make a javascript code in which will use a while loop or for loop in which will go through the variable "list" automatically

Comment: What does not work about your current code? What is the question?

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: [Loops and iteration documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: let me guess... <script type="text/javascript">?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval()` for that in the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
    <img id="trafficlights" src="Redlight.jpeg" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
    <button type="button" onclick="starttrafficlights()">Change Traffic Lights</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="stoptrafficlights()">Stop Traffic Lights</button>
<script>
    var position = 1, id;
    var list = ["Redlight.jpeg","RedAmberlight.jpeg","Greenlight.jpeg", "Amberlight"];  
    function changetrafficlights(){ 
            stop = true;
            var image = document.getElementById('trafficlights');
            image.src=list[position % list.length];
            position++;
    }
    function starttrafficlights(){
        id = setInterval(changetrafficlights, 1000);
    }
    function stoptrafficlights(){
        clearInterval(id);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will automatically change the `img` after the specified duration.

Hope it Helps!!